# In alchemyapi receive all outputs for all URLs

Tags: alchemyapi

I have a spreadsheet which contains column more then 100000 URL that I want to analyze.

With the use of alchemyapi I am able to analyze these links. I analyze the links about their: document sentimental, document emotions,  target sentiment,entities keywords, title.

I am able to receive the output for this analysis for one URL. But to do this for 10000URL’s this will take a lot of time.
Is there a way that I can get the output of my analysis in a CSV file and this for all my records with a URL.

So my question is:
“Is it possible with the use of alchemyapi to perform the analysis(document sentimental, document emotions,  target sentimental , entities, keywords, title) for all URLs in once?
So that I receive a output for all the URLs once.

Comment: alchemy seems to be an api for analyzing one website per request. if you want to analyze 100,000 URL's you have to write a script with a loop. which reads all data from your spreadsheet and write the results to a new one.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to receive output for multiple URLs at once. As mentioned in the comment, the best way to do this would be to loop through each URL using your programming language of choice.

Additionally, as AlchemyAPI was acquired by IBM, the AlchemyLanguage services are now part of [Watson Natural Language Understanding](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/natural-language-understanding.html). More details on the updated version of the APIs can be found there.